# Play! - Interacting with a webapp from the SBT console

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have a Play! 2 application  where I have defined some jobs. These jobs interact with external web services and with the database, hence they need a running application to work.

I would like to be able to launch these jobs as SBT tasks from the Play console. SO I have followed [the guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html) to define my own tasks and I am able to define simple tasks. What I cannot do is importing from the application namespace. I guess this makes some sense - in the context of SBT we may not have an application running.

> Is there some way to write an SBT task where an application is launched and one has access to the application namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need an answer, have you tried to use the Play console?

```
$ play console
```

It loads all your application classes so you can use them as you wish.

See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/PlayConsole for more information :)

Comment: I think I did not explain clearly what I need. There will be no people running these jobs. They may be run by cron, or possibly by some people who do not know Scala or Play. I just need a simple command line interface to the Play application. Now, it *is* possible to define command line tasks in sbt - see the link in my question. The problem is that these tasks do not have access to the application namespace.

Comment: For instance, while this is not my case, say there are many users registering to an application, and one needs to purge those users that have not clicked in a confirmation mail after a week. One may want to define a task called `clean-users` so that running `play clean-users` from cron or from the command line allows to perform this task.

Comment: Ah okay, I see. I'm sorry, I don't think I'll be able to help you then.